# how haproxy define dynamic backend server

Tags: dynamic, acl, backend, haproxy

Recently I have a project that need use haproxy,after I readed the config doc I found the acl.

with the acl I can filter some backends by the request url,that's cool.

But not enough,I want generate a dynamic backend server by the url params which I matched,for example:

```
acl dynamic_ser url_reg /*.(10.0.0.1|10.0.0.2)$

use_backend dynamic_server if dynamic_ser

backend dynamic_server
    balance leastconn
        option httpclose
        server node1 10.0.0.1:8080 
        server node2 10.0.0.2:8080
```

and for my question,the url is dynamic sometimes may be /path?ip=10.0.0.1 and

sometimes may  like this /path?ip=10.0.0.1&10.0.0.2 and may  /path?ip=10.0.0.1&10.0.0.2&10.0.0.3 also.

and everytime I want get the backend server depend on the matched,of couse I can define these servers once a time.but I don't think it's good,any method can I use?

Comment: Have you found answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that & is a delimiter between key-value pairs, so `/path?ip=10.0.0.1&10.0.0.2` is mapped to `{'ip':'10.0.0.1','10.0.0.2':null}`